# Very weird NPE when trying to copy an object

Tags: java, object, copy, clone

I'm trying to copy an object while passing in a parameter to the method I'm using to copy with. In the constructor for the object after I try to copy it the parameter becomes null.

This is the class that I'm trying to copy:

```
 /**
 * Represents the extra health perk
 */
public class ArrowRegen implements Perk
{
    private int id = 0;

    private double chance = 0.15;

    private int level = 0;
    private int price = 1000;
    private int arrowGain = 0;

    private GamePlayer ourPlayer;

    public ArrowRegen(){}

    public ArrowRegen(GamePlayer ourPlayer)
    {
        this.ourPlayer = ourPlayer;

        if(this.ourPlayer == null)
            aa.debug("its null");
    }

    @Override
    public Perk getThisPerk(GamePlayer player)
    {
        aa.debug("returning an arrow regen");

        if(player == null)
            aa.debug("player is null? somehow?");

        return new ArrowRegen(ourPlayer);
    }
}
```

- nothing is null up until the point in the constructor at the "its null" comment. *

This is where I call the copy from:

```
player.addActivePerks(PerkEngine.getPerk(1).getThisPerk(player));
```

(player is a GamePlayer object)

Here is the PerkEngine bit:

```
 /**
 * Gets a perk by it's ID
 * @param id The Perk's ID
 * @return The Perk with the specified ID
 */
public static Perk getPerk(int id)
{
    for(Perk perk : perks)
    {
        if(perk.getID() == id)
        {
            return perk;

        }
    }

    // This will never return null
    return null;
}
```

EDIT:

I just realized my mistake was in the "getThisPerk" method. When returning the new object, I pass in the wrong variable.

Answer (score -1):

I just realized my mistake was in the "getThisPerk" method. When returning the new object, I pass in the wrong variable.